# How to reproduce in the server a pdf generated in the web client by jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, java, spring

To clarify the question, here is the situation: I have a web page which creates a pdf file (based on a graphic generated by flot.js) using raw data get from a web service. I'm using Spring on the server side.
My need is automatically generating the same result (the same pdf file) on the server without any client action.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Actually I didn't try anything yet. Simulate a client in a web browser in the server (using Selenium, for example) could be a solution, but it doesn't seem to be a good solution.